# MVC ViewModel that lives in Session - how to update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have done that the "standard" way:

```
    public ActionResult Respondent()
    {
        return View(Session["Respondent"]); //passing the model
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Respondent(Respondent resp)
    {
        repository.UpdateRespondent(Respondent resp);
        Session["Respondent"] = respondent; //put back into session
        return View(respondent); //redraw view, passing in respondent
    }
```

And it works. I am passing the respondent model only for MVC to collect FORM values automatically, in the POST action, where inside the view I have these for all the properties:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)

    // and so on...
}
```

My question is - if I am already using a Session object (that lives in Session), 
Is there any way I can use the Session object as a Model inside the view, so that HttpPost works including all the validation. How then, the values will get collected and put back into the Session?

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a pretty ugly way to go.  Are you sure you don't want to reserve the Session-driven pages for ordinary ASP.NET Web Forms?  It is possible to mix them both in the same application.  Session is sort of an antiquated concept in the ASP.NET MVC universe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What's wrong with using Session? I have to keep my object in session. It's being used by various views and controllers.

Comment: If I keep passing the object from one action to another, and the action returns partial view, that is a part of another partial view, that is a part of parent view, that is a part of page layout view, how then, I would access the object in all these views, including the page layout view?

Comment: Retrieve all of that from your Model.  Use caching if hitting the database each time is too onerous.  Session implies maintaining state, and MVC web pages should be stateless.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, best practices preaching aside, you CAN pass a session object as a Model.

**2 Caveats:**

1. Session objects should be cast when passed

   return View((RespondentObject)Session["Respondent"])
2. On the View, remember to bind to object type

   @model perseus.Models.RespondentObject

I recommend you read from and write to Session in your Controllers.

You pointed out that you will be using multiple partials to create your form. You have 2 choice:

- Create a Model to be received by Action which includes all objects.
- Pass every parameter individually to your Action.

**You asked why it is bad form to use object:**

- Because they're untypes
- Because Sessions are flaky (unreliable)

That said, you know your app and architecture best. You have to make your decisions and support them. As much as I'm a purist, I believe best practices are a guide not a religion. Circumstances vary.

Comment: Thanks, true. In my app I am using strongly typed session wrapper. So it's not a problem. And, sure I can pass Session object as a model parameter. But I was wondering if I can use the session object inside the View directly, without passing it as a model parameter. Sure, I can access it within a view, but what I dont know is how to update it using Html EditorFor helpers (please see the post) so that the form will put values back into the model by itself.

Comment: Oh, may be I missed somthing... Just trying to understand... If I pass Session object as a model param, upon submission, all the form values will be put back into the Session object?

Comment: the EditorFor binds against a passed model. To use model binding you HAVE to pass. Otherwise if you wanted to use Editor and other non-'For' helpers, you could access the model. But, beware, MVC craves model binding and works best. I would waste your time by trying to point out all the little things that wouldn't be quite right. Especially since you could work past them.

Comment: If you pass the Session-Model to the View, you will be able to bind your helpers against it. But you will be binding against an unconnected model. You would then receive them in your controller and reassign your model to the session. So you are dis-attaching from session to send to View; View sends to Action Method; Action Method would re-populate Session-Model. The disattach, re-atach is important to allow the V and C to communicate by sending the M back and forth. Understandable, you want to short-circuit that, but beware... MVC works best when you work WITH it not against

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dave! I am using "For" helpers for updating the model. I wasn't sure about the "dis-attachment thing", if I pass a session object as a model. I though if I pass a "whatever" object as a model to a view, I am just passing a reference to the object, not a copy of it. Are you sure, inside the View the "Model" is not pointing to the Session object passed as a model parameter ??

Comment: Guarantee it. 'Pass by value'. Completely disconnected. And for good reason. Convention is to pass ORM objects that are connected to DB. If those were passed to a View, either they would be out of scope or worse they would corrupt db

Comment: Great, thanks, I have coded originally as you recommended above. This makes total sense.